# Destroy everything inside a window outside of function Tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, window, destroy

in the code below i would like to destroy everything inside the window root when the GameButton button is pressed, however i would like other things to happen so the only way to do this would be for the button to run a function. When i perform self.destroy outside of the main class, nothing is deleted, is there any way around this?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, BOTH,W, N, E, S, Entry, Text, INSERT, Toplevel
from ttk import Frame, Style, Button, Label
import Tkinter
import Callingwordlist
difficulty = ""

class MainMenuUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("Type!")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        style = Style()
        style.configure("TFrame", background="black")        

        Logo = Image.open("Type!.png")
        TypeLogo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Logo)
        label1 = Label(self, image=TypeLogo)
        label1.image = TypeLogo
        label1.place(x=342,y=80)
        label1.pack()

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        GameButton = Button(self, text="Main Game", command=lambda: main2(self.parent,self))
        GameButton.pack()
        GameButton.place(x=344,y=200,height = 80,width = 176)

        TutorialButton = Button(self,text="Tutorial Level")
        TutorialButton.pack()
        TutorialButton.place(x=344, y=300 ,height = 80,width = 176)

        quitbutton = Button(self, text= "Quit",command=self.parent.destroy)
        quitbutton.place(x=344, y=400,height = 80,width = 176)

def main2(root,self):
    self.destroy
    app = MainGameUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

class MainGameUI(root):
    ....

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("860x640+300+300")
    app = MainMenuUI(root) 
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually destroying anything in your function. Look at this code:

```
def main2(root,self):
    self.destroy
    app = MainGameUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Notice the first line in the function where you are trying to destroy everything. Your code is `self.destroy` - notice the lack of parenthesis. You aren't actually *calling* the function, you are simply referencing it. Add parentheses to call it: `self.destroy()`.

You have another problem in that you're calling a function that destroys the widget that calls the function. However, this function enters into an endless loop (`mainloop()`), so the button command will never return. I'm not entirely sure what will happen here, you'll probably get some sort of error. The bottom line is, calling `mainloop` from a button command is not a good idea.

Since you are structuring your app such that the app is a frame (rather than the root window) you don't need to restart the event loop. When you destroy the `MainMenuUI` widget, the event loop will continue to run. There's no need to restart it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, everything is working dandy now and removing root.mainloop reduced my code a bit